Benepar for syntactic segmentation
I want to use Benepar with a French model to do a syntactic segmentation.
I followed the tutorial but I have always have this error

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ChartParser:
Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "pretrained_model.embeddings.position_ids".

I tried to do the following:
import benepar
benepar.download('benepar_fr2')
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('fr_core_news_sm')
parser = benepar.Parser("benepar_fr2")

def parse_sentence(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    parsed_sents = [parser.parse(sent.text) for sent in doc.sents]
    return parsed_sents

sentence = "Le chat mange une souris."
parsed_sentence = parse_sentence(sentence)
print(parsed_sentence)


Please [edit] to provide the full traceback, not just the last line of it.

Do you know how to get it ?

You get the traceback when you get the error message; we want you to copy/paste all of it so that we can see which line exactly caused the error and what the call stack looked like at that point.

The English example (using benepar_en3) still works with pytorch 2.5. But I am seeing the same RuntimeError for German (benepar_de2).

Likely an issue with the pytorch version. Benepar seems to be developed with pytorch 1.6.0, but it's unclear if newer versions will still work.

I was able to work around this error and get useful parse results by changing the strict default in line 2477 of file torch/nn/modules/module.py from True to False:
self, state_dict: Mapping[str, Any], strict: bool = False, assign: bool = False

Tested for German and French. Ubuntu 24.10, python 3.12.7
A cleaner solution would be very welcome.
